# Should High Vacuum oil smell?

Tags: boiling-point, smell

I recently have purchased a high vacuum pump and am currently repairing it, the internals have a strong smell of oil. I was going to do an oil change anyway but should I clean all the old oil. High vacuum oil shouldn't have a smell because that would indicate out-gassing? Is that right?

Comment: New oil has very little odor. Used oil can definitely carry odors depending on what has run through the pump and the condition of the pump (overheating is bad).

Comment: If it smells then it contains either burned oil or lots of  whatever has been pumped through it.  Definitely clean out as much oil as you can, use solvents only if you must, then when completely dry, and, if you can,  bake the whole darn thing for ages to get rid of any remaining volatile stuff.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much. Clean out what you can, refill, and let the pump run with the ballast valve open (and perhaps with a small leak in your apparatus) for a while.

Comment: Oh, somehow the first edit didnt save properly, it is a turbomolecular pump.